# Can't select a Candidate version from package as it has no candidate

Tags: ubuntu, apt, deb

I have a problem about downloading `nmap` and its dependencies (to install offline) from an Ubuntu 16.04 computer.

When executing:

```
apt-get download $(apt-rdepends nmap |grep -v "^ ")
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Can't select candidate version from package libblas.so.3 as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package debconf-2.0 as it has no candidate
```

I tried solving the error using `apt-get update` which did not help.
Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-2.0
```

You will get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package debconf-2.0 is a virtual package provided by:
debconf 1.5.58ubuntu1
cdebconf 0.198ubuntu1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Instead of using debconf-2.0, you should use debconf:

```
sudo apt-get download debconf
```